# The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
 xmlnode = xmldoc.CreateElement(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
 xmlroot.AppendChild(xmlnode);     
 xmlnode.InnerText = sub;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
string name = XmlConvert.EncodeName(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

to get a safe encoded name, then

```
xmlnode = xmldoc.CreateElement(name);
```

however; as Jon notes, this is highly unusual - and an encoded name is not pretty; for example `a=b` becomes `a_x003D_b`.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the value of `dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString()`. It sounds like it isn't a valid element name, due to including an `=` sign.

It's relatively rare to create an element with a *name* given dynamically from data. It's more common to specify the *content* of an element that way.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's in your row?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to export a Microsoft  catalog to XML, the resulting file cannot be imported, and you receive the following error message
"The XML file path/filename contains an error at line. " "A Name contained an invalid character."
If you validate the XML catalog by using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET  you receive the following error message:
"The '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot begin a name. Line #, Position #"
This problem occurs because the Commerce Server export was not encoding the following special characters:

```
The range 0x0021 – 0x002F includes ! “ # $ % & ‘ ( ) * + , - . /
The range 0x03A – 0x0040 includes : ; < = > ? @
The range 0x007B – 0x007E includes { | } ~
The range 0x005B – 0x005E [ \ ] ^**
```

Answer (score -2):

The title is your answer. You can't use '=' in a name.